# AttributeError: lpoApp instance has no attribute 'database'

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I've read several threads on this program, and it seems the common solution is *improper indentation*. I've tested my code using `PEP8` online tools, and manually went through line by line and am not finding any issues with my indentation, so I suspect it is what the error:

```
AttributeError: lpoApp instance has no attribute 'database'
```

I've been looking in to this for a few hours now and am stumped. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

The following is the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/CodeClinic/lpoApp.py", line 213, in <module>
    main()
  File "/CodeClinic/lpoApp.py", line 209, in main
    app = lpoApp(root)
  File "/CodeClinic/lpoApp.py", line 27, in __init__
    self._createGUI()
  File "/CodeClinic/lpoApp.py", line 94, in _createGUI
    ttk.Button(self.frame_input, text='Submit', command=self._submit_callback()).grid(
  File "/CodeClinic/lpoApp.py", line 166, in _submit_callback
    data = list(self.database.get_data_for_range(start, end))
AttributeError: lpoApp instance has no attribute 'database'
```

Let's work out way through it, starting with the call to main():

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Which invokes the app:

```
def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = lpoApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Now, that we created an instance of the `lpoApp` inside of the root `Tk` window, the `lpoApp` constructor has been called. This is where we should be instantiating `lpoDB` (which has been imported) as `self.database`:

```
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self._createGUI()
        self.database = lpoDB.lpoDB()
        self.master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self._safe_close)
```

And in  `_createGUI()` method we bind `self._submit_callback()` to the `Submit` button command. So let's take a peak at that:

```
    ttk.Button(self.frame_input, text='Submit',         
              command=self._submit_callback()).grid(row=2, column=0,
              columnspan=9, padx=5)
```

Now, our `Submit` button has a callback to lpoApp's `_submit_callback()` method:

```
def _submit_callback(self):
    # I printed `start` and `end` at this point prior to 
    # passing them in to the next call and they had valid
    # datetime formats that get_data_for_range is expecting

    data = list(self.database.get_data_for_range(start, end))
```

Using my favourite IDE PyCharm, I ran through the code in debug mode which allows me to inspect the attribute's of `self`. `self.database` was not listed. Hence, somehow the interpreter is passing over that declaration and not instantiating my DB connection.

Any ideas on why this would be happening, or what I can do to further test/debug this?

Comment: I have a running theory; my different code editors may have mixed spaces and tabs. I'm testing this theory now... Just fyi.

Comment: Running my code from the CLI with `python lpoApp.py -t` did not provide any feedback. I `man python` for my version to verify it was -t and not --tt too :(

Comment: I just converted my Project so all tabs were converted to spaces and I am still getting this error. Darn it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70496/discussion-between-drobuddy-and-rinzler).

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that your `_createGUI` method on `lpoApp` references `database` before it is assigned:

```
Traceback:
  ...
  File "/CodeClinic/lpoApp.py", line 27, in __init__
    self._createGUI()
  File "/CodeClinic/lpoApp.py", line 94, in _createGUI
    ttk.Button(self.frame_input, text='Submit', command=self._submit_callback()).grid(
  File "/CodeClinic/lpoApp.py", line 166, in _submit_callback
    data = list(self.database.get_data_for_range(start, end))
AttributeError: lpoApp instance has no attribute 'database'
```

where you clearly define your database connection after calling `_createGUI` during instantiation of `lpoApp`:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    self._createGUI()
    self.database = lpoDB.lpoDB()
    self.master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self._safe_close)
```

Shift your `self.database = lpoDB.lpoDB()` line above the call to `_createGUI` like so:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    self.database = lpoDB.lpoDB()
    self._createGUI()
    self.master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self._safe_close)
```

Comment: Rinzler pointed that out to me, as well. Good catch. ;)

This is why it's good to take breaks, lol. Thanks, nelfin.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are calling `self._createGUI()` before instantiating a property called `self.database`. That's why when you are associating the command of the button `Submit` the method `_submit_callback()`, and Python is parsing, it will have not found yet `self.database` anywhere.

Comment: Yup, exactly. Thanks, Rinzler.